# javafx don't loss the focus when click other node

Tags: java, javafx

I have a vbox on left of rootpane,and a vbox on right of rootpane.
leftvobx have 3 textarea nodes,rightvbox have a colorpicker;
I want:  when I choose one textarea node on leftvbox, then to click colorpicker on rightvbox, the current textarea don't loss the focus.

My idea is same as "Scene builder" , when we select a note in the workspace, then to handle the right slide function area(like change color,set size and font),the note will not lose focus, so the action know which node in workspace need handle.

Code:
        VBox leftBox = new VBox();
        VBox rightBox = new VBox();

```
    leftBox.setPrefSize(200, 250);
    rightBox.setPrefSize(200, 250);

    leftBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue");

    Button btn1 = new Button("First");
    Button btn2 = new Button("Second");
    Button btn3 = new Button("Third");

    ColorPicker colorpicker = new ColorPicker();

    leftBox.getChildren().addAll(btn1,btn2,btn3);
    rightBox.getChildren().add(colorpicker);

    colorpicker.setOnAction(e->{
            if(btn2.isFocused()){

            btn2.setText("color changed.");
        }
    });

    HBox root = new HBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(leftBox,rightBox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfDmG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to have two nodes focused afaik. That would be very weird, since every keyboard event etc would go to two nodes. In the JavaFX scene builder as well, you can try it. Click on something in the SceneBuilder and press delete, it will be deleted. Press on something in the SceneBuilder and then on the right and press delete and the item you selected first will not be deleted. Because it doesn't actually have focus. SceneBuilder just shows you what you had last selected.

To solve your problem. I would make a new Variable `Button lastFocused;` and make Listeners on the other Buttons `focusedProperty` something like this:

```
btn2.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
    if(!newValue) lastFocused = btn2;
});
```

This should store the Button in the new variable as soon as it looses focus. As it looses focus when you focus the color picker, the variable will have the Button that was selected when the color picker got selected.

Now in the color picker something like this should work:

```
colorpicker.setOnAction(e->{
    lastFocused.setText("color changed.");
    lastFocused.requestFocus();
});
```

I have not actually tested the code.

Comment: Maybe I describe it wrong. Scene builder have 3 sections, left section to choose containers,controls,menu and so on. Mid section is the main work area, and right section is to set the properties and layout and core. So when we select a node in mid section of Scene builder, then to right section to set the layout and properties on right function area of Scene builder, the node didn't lost focus. Think about this, if the node lost the focus, on right area,

Comment: @A.Sheh I think you described it correct. But still, the node looses actual focus. It just looks like it has focus. You can do that with styling. The look of it having focus is nothing else than styling of the button. But actual focus means that it receives the keyboard input, and in the Scenebuilder the Node in the center does not receive the keyboard input as described in my answer.

Comment: So how can i come true this function. I hope do same thing, when I select a node in left pane, and set its style (like color, size, font) in another right pane. However, when I set style, it need to know which node is set.

Comment: The variable lastFocused will contain the button that was selected in the left pane before you went to the color picker.